# Looking for help to solve system of linear equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

its been a while since I have done any system of equations questions so I was looking for help

The first equation is             $ax+by=u$

The next  equation is     $cx + dy = x$

And I have to solve for x and y, any guidance at all would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried? **Hint:** express $y$ in terms of $x$ using the first equation and then substitute into the second to find $x$  **OR** multiply the first by $d$ and, the second by $b$ and subtract the two.

Comment: @Äres I tried this to begin with but I didn't seem to get anywhere im afraid

Answer (score 0):

We can consider the cases where the constants are zero separately.

From the first equation we obtain $$y=\frac{u-ax}{b}$$ and substituting into the second gives $$cx+d(\frac{u-ax}{b})=x(c-\frac{da}{b})+\frac{du}{b}=x$$
$$x(c-\frac{da}{b}-1)=-\frac{du}{b}$$ and thus $$x=\frac{-\frac{du}{b}}{c-\frac{da}{b}-1}=\frac{du}{b(1-c)+da}$$

and $$y=\frac{u-ax}{b}=\frac{u-a(\frac{du}{b(1-c)+da})}{b}=\frac{u}{b}-\frac{adu}{b(b(1-c)+da)}.$$